# FileObserver not detecting files in specified directories

Tags: java, android, file, local-storage, fileobserver

I'm developing an Android application that utilizes a FileObserver to monitor specific directories for file creation events. However, despite implementing the FileObserver and ensuring the correct paths and permissions, the observer does not detect any files in the specified directories.

I have implemented a FileMonitoringService in my Android application to monitor directories for file creation events using a FileObserver. The service is started correctly, and logging indicates that the FileObserver is initialized and started successfully.

I used two directories as a source and destination directories for test purpuse. The directories being monitored are /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/Sent and /storage/emulated/0/Telegram/hh. These paths are double-checked to ensure their correctness.

I have verified that my app has the necessary permissions to access external storage and the specified directories. There are no runtime permission issues reported.

Using a file manager app on the device, I've manually confirmed that the directories being monitored exist and contain files. Additionally, I've placed test files directly within these directories to check if they trigger any events, but no detections occur.

I've added extensive logging statements within the FileObserver implementation, including within the onEvent() method, to trace the execution flow and verify if events are being triggered. However, no events are detected.

One notable error message observed in the logs is related to an ioctl operation (ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument). While it's unclear if this error directly affects the file monitoring process, it's worth investigating further.

I'm seeking guidance on resolving this issue with the FileObserver not detecting files despite correct setup, paths, and permissions. I mention my code bellow is there have any problem.

```
private void startFileMonitoring() {
        if (sourcepath != null && destinationpath != null) {
            Log.e("FileMonitoringService", sourcepath);
            Log.e("FileMonitoringService", destinationpath);
            File sourceDir = new File(sourcepath);
            File destinationDir = new File(destinationpath);

            if (!sourceDir.exists() || !destinationDir.exists()) {
                // Log an error if either source or destination directory does not exist
                Log.e("FileMonitoringService", "Source or destination directory does not exist");
                return;
            }

            Log.d("FileMonitoringService", "Starting file monitoring...");
            Log.d("FileMonitoringService", "Starting file monitoring..." + sourceDir);
            // Initialize fileObserver and start watching
            fileObserver = new FileObserver(sourcepath, FileObserver.CREATE) {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(int event, String path) {

                    // Log the full event details for debugging
                    Log.d("FileMonitoringService", "Event: " + event + ", Path: " + path);

                    // Copy the file to the destination folder
                    File sourceFile = new File(sourcepath + "/" + path);
                    File destinationFile = new File(destinationpath + "/" + path);
                    try {
                        // Ensure the source file exists
                        if (sourceFile.exists()) {
                            // Create parent directories for the destination file
                            if (!destinationFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
                                destinationFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                            }
                            // Copy the file
                            copyFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                            Log.d("FileMonitoringService", "File copied to destination: " + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        } else {
                            // Log if the source file doesn't exist
                            Log.e("FileMonitoringService", "Source file doesn't exist: " + sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("FileMonitoringService", "Error copying file: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };
            fileObserver.startWatching();
            Log.d("FileMonitoringService", "File monitoring started.");
        } else {
            // Log an error if source or destination path is null
            Log.e("FileMonitoringService", "Source or destination path is null");
        }
    }
```

Any insights, suggestions, or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can your app list the files in mentioned directories? I assume your app will not be able to detect and read files of other apps on Android 11+ devices.

Comment: For what do you need a destination directory,?

Comment: simply i want to detect media files from whatsapp Images folder and instantly copy each detected media files into another folder. simply this is a app like auto file transfer app(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.noople.autotransfer.lite&pcampaignid=web_share). actualy here i am cloning that app.

Comment: Strange you did not tell that before. Please answer and react to my first comment as even if the observer would work you would not have access to the file was the message.